# Let classes inherit from type aliases

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, flowtype

I try to create a user class and want to be able to inherit from a type alias:

```
type PlainUser = { email: string }

class User extends PlainUser {
  constructor (initialValues: PlainUser) {
    this.email = initialValues.email
  }

  update () { ... }
}
```

This doesn't work of course, but I would like to have the following semantics without having to duplicate `email` (and all the other fields that I don't show to keep it brief):

```
type PlainUser = { email: string }

class User {
  email: string

  constructor (initialValues: PlainUser) {
    this.email = initialValues.email
  }

  update () { ... }
}
```

Is this possible with flow?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but you can at least use `implements` to enforce that the `User` class implements the `PlainUser` interface (yes, you have to change it to be an interface).

```
interface PlainUser {
  email: string;
}

class Foo implements PlainUser {
}
```

([tryflow](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAdgFwKYBOUAhgMZ5gAKMx2AqgM6FgDeqYYeAtrTAFxgGOAtgDmAblQBfdKRoMGYAGJw4YDFwAOMbnlyLqtLI2ZspQA))

The code above yields the following error with Flow v0.41, since `Foo` does not specify an `email` property:

```
7: class Foo implements PlainUser {
                        ^ property `email` of PlainUser. Property not found in
7: class Foo implements PlainUser {
         ^ Foo
```

Of course, this isn't exactly what you've asked for. But at least you are getting automatic checking that `User` implements `PlainUser`, rather than nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can only extend from classes, and your type alias is an interface, so you have to use `implement` here. TypeScript Salsa allows doing the following since [this suggestion was implemented](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4955):

```
type PlainUser = { email: string };

class User implements PlainUser {
  constructor (initialValues: PlainUser) {
      this.email = initialValues.email;
  }
}
```

If you do not use salsa, you have to explicitly declare the inherited properties:

```
type PlainUser = { email: string };

class User implements PlainUser {
    public email: string;
    constructor (initialValues: PlainUser) {
        this.email = initialValues.email;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20PlainUser%20%3D%20%7B%20email%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass%20User%20implements%20PlainUser%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20email%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%20(initialValues%3A%20PlainUser)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.email%20%3D%20initialValues.email%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: The question is about Flowtype, so this does not seem to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit this was a head scratcher initially, but something like what you want to do is very possible. It does require rethinking the approach a bit.

First, you need to start with the `class` instead of the object literal. Intuitively this makes sense, as that's also the way javascript works.

```
class User {
  email: string;
}
```

Next you want to use flow's `$Shape` transformation. This will cast your type to the enumerable properties of the class.

```
type PlainUser = $Shape<User>;

const Bob: PlainUser = { email: "bob@bob.com" }
```

or

```
const BobProperties: PlainUser = { ...new PlainUserClass("bob@bob.com") }
```

Finally, extend the User class as normal.

```
class AdminUser extends User {
  admin: true;
}
```

[example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsABRwEsA7AVVwFMAnAYR3zAG9UwxqBbbEmALjC4ALrXIBzANyoAvugxwyIsAFcatQS048+gkWLLiwMsAF4wZakmK9K6xnlwAKAJTzFyuMIAWdKnUEAEgBlb2wAB2oAHhtyfwYmXAA+M1ZtXgEwAHIoODgs40wPYTAAIQB5UqDQiOjYuzoHfBTzLQA6DstrUgaEx1dC+USwADE8zgAPYWoyABMCevimgjYOBSVRFQxhOFoncNo4cNwXVY4hFUi9g6OT9nOfElw27gzUm+OXnRhpDjkZIA)